# What did the very last scene mean?

Tags: analysis, ending, are-you-here

I just watched [*Are You Here* (2013)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1545754/), and the very ending confused me.  Ben (played by Zach Galifianakis) has met his new neighbor and runs into her in a store.  He walks outside and it's raining.  His new neighbor's son wants to ride an electric horse, so he puts the child on the horse.  Ben then sees a real horse being driven through the parking lot.  There is a close-up of the horse's head, then it switches to a close-up of the electric horse's head that the child is riding.

Was there some meaning to that scene that I missed?  Was there some intended comparison to the two horses?  I can't shake the feeling I was supposed to take something away from that scene, yet it's completely escaping me.

Comment: If you live near Austin, TX you can go and read the original script plus various drafts and redrafts; https://norman.hrc.utexas.edu/fasearch/findingAid.cfm?eadid=01160#